# InterShop dates comparison condition doesn't work

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements, intershop

I have a condition which doesn't work:

```
<isif condition="#(Product:QLC_ValidTo > current_date)#">                        
    <span class="items-in-stock align-left">
        <isinclude template="product/inc/CC_StockStatus"/>
    </span>
</isif>
```

There are two valid values for both operands:

Product:QLC_ValidTo = 29.11.16
and
current_date = 13.10.17

but it doesn't work.

I suppose is it incorrect to try to implement it as a simple comparison and values should be converted to another format?

Comment: Already gave u an answer on this. Is there a reason you want to do this in isml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [intershop get date in .isml template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728270/intershop-get-date-in-isml-template)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't agree with the following approach, see my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728270/intershop-get-date-in-isml-template) post. If you insist on only isml then you can do the following.

```
<%
    getPipelineDictionary().put("current_date",new Date());
%>
<isif condition="#(Product:QLC_ValidTo:getTime > current_date:getTime)#">                        
    <span class="items-in-stock align-left">
        <isinclude template="product/inc/CC_StockStatus"/>
    </span>
</isif>
```

Retrieve the milliseconds as a long and comparing it with gt operator. These operator only work with numbers.

Like it said before, rather do this in an extension. You can unit test it, deal with timezone issues, readability would improve etc.